# With Django/Python Open a temp file in memory outside of the function it was created in

Tags: django, python-3.x, csv

I'm having the worst time with this one. In a view I created a csv file that's saved to memory. I need to get that csv file to a utils.py function and post to an external api. I for the life of me can not figure out how to do this and it's really driving me nuts.

I originally was just trying to create it in the run_test_suite_in_hatit function below and then somehow open it in the run_all_modal below but that wasn't working. What occurred below was the file (hatit_csv_filename) was now a message object. I don't want to save it to a model as its temporary and is being created purely to be sent right in a api post within HATScript() which is in a utils.py file within the same app in the my project. I'm not sure how to get the file to HATScript() which is just making me nuts.

```
def run_test_suite_in_hatit(request):
    testrail_suite_id = int(request.GET['suite'])
    print(testrail_suite_id)
    testrail_instance = TestRailInstance.objects.first()
    project = request.user.humanresource.project
    testrail_project_id = project.testrail.project_id
    testrail_project = get_testrail_project(testrail_instance, testrail_project_id)
    testrail_suites = testrail_project.get_suites()
    testrail_suite = [s for s in testrail_suites if s.id == testrail_suite_id][0]
    testrail_cases = testrail_suite.get_cases()
    hatit_csv_filename = bulk_hatit_file_generator(testrail_cases)
    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, hatit_csv_filename)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/run_all_modal/')


def run_all_modal(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestRunnerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            scripts = get_messages(request)
            csvfile = ""
            for script in scripts:
                csvfile = script
            hs = HATScript()
            hs.apn = data.get('apn')
            hs.holly_server = data.get('browser')
            hs.basic_connection_test()
            response = hs.hatit_execute()
        else:
            print(form.errors)

        return JsonResponse({'success': True})
```

---

EDIT: SOLVED
I have been bashing my head over this and it was so obvious what I needed to do !

Updated View functions:

```
def run_test_suite_in_hatit(request):
    testrail_suite_id = int(request.GET['suite'])
    testrail_instance = TestRailInstance.objects.first()
    project = request.user.humanresource.project
    testrail_project_id = project.testrail.project_id
    testrail_project = get_testrail_project(testrail_instance, testrail_project_id)
    testrail_suites = testrail_project.get_suites()
    testrail_suite = [s for s in testrail_suites if s.id == testrail_suite_id][0]
    testrail_cases = testrail_suite.get_cases()
    hatit_csv_filename = bulk_hatit_file_generator(testrail_cases)
    **HATScript.csvfile = hatit_csv_filename**
    return 'runner/run_all_modal.html'


def run_all_modal(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestRunnerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            hs = HATScript()
            **hs.csvfile = HATScript.csvfile**
            hs.apn = data.get('apn')
            hs.holly_server = data.get('browser')
            response = hs.hatit_execute()
            print(response.status_code)
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    return redirect('runner:dashboard')
```

I was trying to send to a function within a class and populate the variables with the appropriate data but because the data was coming from 2 different Views I was beside myself on how to achieve this. I have tried so many ridiculous things. I removed any proprietary bits.

```
class HATScript(AutomationScript):
    def __init__(self, apn='', body='', dialed_number='',
                 holly_server='', sonus_server='',
                 hatit_server='',
                 remote_server=' ', remote_user='', remote_password=''):

        self.csvfile = ''
        self.hatit_server = hatit_server
        self.apn = apn
        self.dialed_number = dialed_number
        self.body = body
        self.filename = ''
        self.holly_server = holly_server
        self.sonus_server = sonus_server
        self.remote_server = remote_server
        self.remote_user = remote_user
        self.remote_password = remote_password

    def hatit_execute(self):
        """Uses Frank's HAT User Interface to initate a HAT test"""
        browser = requests.session()
        stuff = browser.get('http://{0}/hatit'.format(self.remote_server))
        print(stuff.status_code)
        data = {'apn': self.apn,
                'browser': self.holly_server,
                'port': '5060'}
        response = browser.post("http://{0}/".format(self.hatit_server), data=data, files={'csvfile': open(self.csvfile)})

        print(response.text)
        browser.close()
        return response
```

Essentially I was able to assign the variable the file in the run_test_suite_in_hatit(request) function and had to [this SO question helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)  me understand working with Class variables and assigning to them etc. Which helped me solve  the issue I've been having for so long that I came into work on it more on a Saturday night.

Comment: Note that `for script in scripts: csvfile = script` in your code will overwrite `csvfile` in every iteration. Therefore, it is the same as `csvfile = scripts[-1]`.